# Send post data to asp.net page from classic asp

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

The goal is to popup an asp.net page from classic asp using post data, however, the asp.net page always has Request.Form variables as empty and shows RequestType get.

1. I have stripped all the code from asp out, tested receiving the form variables sent from an html page on the asp.net page and this works fine.  Copying the same form html to the asp page still gives no request.form data and a RequestType get

   ```
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
       <form method="post" name="form" action="http://localhost:51307">
           <input name="uid" value="1" />
           <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
       </form>
   </body>
   ```

The asp site is using frames and the form is sent from a child frame, I'm unsure if this is the issue.

2.
Assuming this worked, I had thought to submit a form in asp and use the onsubmit event of the form to popup the page which would send the form variables as post data.  Is this the best way of doing this?

**UPDATE**
The frames seem to be at fault here somehow, I have posted from the form within the framed page to another classic asp page and then redirected from this to the asp.net page.

Comment: I guess it's because "Navigate windows and frames across different domains" is disabled by default which probably means you can't pass form data due to security reasons. So the problem is now solved when you don't use frames?

Comment: Yes it seems to be working but I will want to do it from the frames in the future, can you pop the Navigate Windows.. in an answer and I'll accept it as this is the real issue.

Comment: Shadow Wizard - Do you want to put the above comment in answer for me to accept?

Comment: Sure @Paul, didn't get notification about your previous comment. Done that now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably happened because "Navigate windows and frames across different domains" is disabled by default in IE browsers, which means you can't pass form data due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET requires certain form fields to be set (usually as hidden fields, though HTTP POST obviously does not know the difference) for an inbound request to be treated as valid, thereby populating the relevant variables.

If I recall, you need to set __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT, and __VIEWSTATE.

Then, your ASP.NET code needs to be able to handle what was sent, as the default handlers will expect there to be something in `__VIEWSTATE` at a minimum.  So, you would need to override the ViewState handler in your page.  I can update with more information later when I'm at work, since I know I've done this before.

Comment: This makes sense, however, asp.net normally accepts request.form happily and it all works when I go into notepad, add the form with method post and submit by opening this in a browser but not when the same form is in the asp page, in the frame.

Comment: Those things are required only if you want "real" PostBack or to preserve the ViewState.. otherwise Request.Form in ASP.NET will behave exactly the same way like it behaves in classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the redirect.  When you redirect a page, it creates a GET request instead of a POST request, and therefore will not have any form data.

Your options are to :

1. Append the form values to the query string.
2. Dynamically generate the form corresponding to the posted `Request.Form` collection, and submit it to the ASP.NET page using Javascript during the `body onload` event.

Comment: Judging from the question and code, he clicked submit button of form with `method="post"` so that's not the case here.

Comment: Read his update.  He submits the form to a page in another frame, and then calls a redirect from that frame.  This generates a get request.